# Get string between characters in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have text file, which has data like this:

```
asd.www.aaa.com
abc.abc.co 
look at me
asd.www.bbb.com
bzc.bzc.co
asd.www.ddd.com
hello world
www.eee.com
xx.yy.z
```

I want strings which is surrounded by `"asd.www.[i want this string].com"`.

So my output will be like:

```
aaa
bbb
ddd
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
grep -Po '^asd\.www\.\K[^.]*(?=\.com)' file
```

if `asd` could be in middle of the string, remove the first `^`.

there could be other corner cases, like the greedy matching etc. it depends on your source input.

Comment: Thanks for solution. But i have problem that i can't put my variable inside it. for example, i had a variable "myvar" and i want to replace it instead of "www" string in the formula. i tried "${myvar}" but it didnt work. How can i do?

Comment: @AloneInTheDark single quote won't expand shell var, try using double qoutes instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suggested `cut` originally but I misread your question. So I'm going to post an alternative with `awk` instead. You are looking for the third column of your text input where there are a total of four columns.

```
less file.txt | awk -F '.' '{ if ($4 != "") print $3 }'
```

It splits your string on `.` and only prints out column `$3` if column `$4` is blank. This should yield the following given your example text:

```
aaa
bbb
ddd
```